# Obfuscating background.js of Electron app (in Next.js framework, nextron)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, electron, obfuscation

I'm trying to figure out how to obfuscate the background.js file of my Electron app (build in the nextron framework). I realized that when I unpack the app.asar file, I see that my authentication flow that I had added on the backend is not obfuscated to the extent I would like. It looks like the background.js is slightly "uglified" but is not obfuscated. I don't want to risk someone being able to remove authentication from the app easily. How could I obfuscate the background.js file? Can someone unpack the app.asar, remove the authentication, pack it, and then create and application without authentication, or something along those lines?

My next.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const JavaScriptObfuscator = require('webpack-obfuscator');
const BytenodeWebpackPlugin = require('../utils/BytenodeWebpackPlugin');
const CheckSumWebpackPlugin = require('../utils/CheckSumWebpackPlugin');

const prodPlugins = [
  new JavaScriptObfuscator({
    compact: true,
    controlFlowFlattening: true,
    controlFlowFlatteningThreshold: 0.75,
    deadCodeInjection: false,
    deadCodeInjectionThreshold: 0.75,
    debugProtection: false,
    debugProtectionInterval: false,
    disableConsoleOutput: false,
    domainLock: [],
    log: true,
    mangle: true,
    renameGlobals: false,
    reservedNames: [],
    rotateStringArray: true,
    seed: 1,
    selfDefending: false,
    sourceMap: false,
    sourceMapBaseUrl: '',
    sourceMapFileName: '',
    sourceMapMode: 'separate',
    stringArray: true,
    target: 'node',
    unicodeEscapeSequence: false,
    identifierNamesGenerator: 'mangled',
    stringArrayEncoding: 'rc4',
  }),
  new BytenodeWebpackPlugin(),
];

module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { dev: isDev }) => Object.assign(
    config,
    {
      target: 'electron-renderer',
      plugins: [
        ...(config.plugins || []),
        ...(!isDev ? prodPlugins : []),
      ],
    },
    !isDev ? { devtool: false } : {},
  ),
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: "_Can someone unpack the app.asar, remove the authentication, pack it, and then create and application without authentication, or something along those lines?_" definitely yes, it is only a matter of time and motivation. If your service has no monetary value, I doubt anyone would be motivated enough. In any case, the question is rather what you want to protect through authentication, as there are many other ways to protect it, depending on what it is.

Comment: @ghybs How do I make that time as long as possible? The app has monetary value

Comment: You should rather detail what you need to protect. As explained above, there are many ways to increase protection, depending on what is at stake.